# How to use Conscrypt library for ssl socketchannel in android?

Tags: android, socketchannel, tcpsocket, sslengine

On the conscrypt [git page](https://github.com/google/conscrypt) , there are no sample usage available to use the conscrypt for ssl socketChannel with sslEngine. Could anyone please provide sample usage example or guide me how to use conscrypt to make NIO socketchannel tcp socket with server(tcp based ssl server).